# php.ini version and apache php version is a different

Tags: php, apache

I installed php 8.1 and some of my sites are not working. I select version php 7.4

use the command `update-alternatives --config php`

and apache2 shows that the version is selected. But the Apache server itself runs php 8.1 this proves the php.ini file and not working sites. How do I back to php 7.4?

I've also tried making changes like:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php73 .php
```

in a .htaccess

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php74-fcgi .php
</IfModule>
```

So doesn't work at all, I no have idea the next steps...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGQoj.png)

Comment: the problem is in the additional config file apache2/conf-available, enable php8.1-fpm.conf, does anyone know how to disable additional config file?

Answer (score 1):

turned out to be easier than it was, after disabling the additional config, you can freely switch between versions php

```
a2disconf php8.1-fpm.conf
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).